# Qt5: Tell QPlainTextEdit to ignore syntax highlighting changes

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, qt5, textchanged, qplaintextedit

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` widget in my application which has a `QSyntaxHighlighter` assigned to it. Upon each content change within that text edit area, I need to get a notification (to update the global application save/changed state). However, the signal `textChanged()` also gets emitted each time the highlighter gets to work, which I need to filter out somehow.

I already had a look at [`modificationChanged()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qplaintextedit.html#modificationChanged), but that doesn't seem to work either. It ignores the highlighting changes and successfully notifies me upon the first content change, but not of any subsequent changes. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qplaintextedit.html#modificationChanged) mentions, that I should be able to reset the internal state with `setModified(false)` but that method doesn't seem to exist.

Any ideas on how to filter the changes?

Do I have to switch to `QTextDocument` which seems to have a single `contentsChanged()` that [is said](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/16964-QTextEdit-Highlighting-and-textChanged%28%29?p=85189#post85189) to ignore syntax highlighting changes?

Comment: Have you looked at [Event filters](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html)?

Comment: @otisonoza Can you please elaborate how they might help in my case? I want to get notified of the `textChanged` signal but just not when caused by the highlighting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out I already was on the right track...just not all the way:

I indeed need to listen to `modificationChanged` signals since they are emitted on content changes (which are the relevant events for my application save state handling).

I however originally did not see a way to reset the internal modification state (e.g. when my application saves its state). The reason was that `setModified(bool)` does not exist for the `QPlainTextEdit`, but I realized that each of those objects has a `QTextDocument` internally which *does* have that method. So I simply call that each time I need to reset the state to non-modified:

```cpp
m_pPlainTextEdit->document()->setModified(false);
```

As a result, when the content is changed the next time, `modificationChanged` will get emitted again so that I can react to it and for example enable the "Save" icon.

*BTW:* The signal `contentsChanged` from `QTextDocument` is also emitted upon formatting changes, so not helpful in my scenario.

Comment: Thanks, also modificationChanged signal has a boolean argument that is useful for enabling and disabling the save button state

`void Dialog::on_plainTextEdit_modificationChanged(bool arg1)
{
    ui->saveQPushButton->setEnabled(arg1);
`}

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, it is just basically an idea.

When the user modifies the text, it is a [QKeyEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html).
When the highlighter does, it is some sort of [QInputMethodEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputmethodevent.html) (?)

What you could do is, check if the event is a QKeyEvent, and if it is not, block it.

You can create a filterobject class, or just define the following method in the class that contains the QTextEdit.

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QKeyEvent) //The user modified the text edit
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

And you have to install it (for example in the constructor), if you defined it in the class that contains QTextEdit:

```
myTextEdit->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: I will have a more detailed look at your idea, but I fear that it will not work, because it is not the `mySyntaxHighlighter` that is generating the event/signal but the `QPlainTextEdit`. And I do want that event in general, just not when caused by the text changes from the highlighter, but only if caused by the user (if he/she edits the text/content).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hooking into modificationChanged(), and resetting the modified flag everytime, you could just hook into textChanged(). It's triggered anytime you make a change to the document, regardless if had been previously changed or not...

Comment: Yes, but I don't want that event if change was triggered by the QHighlighter. So that doesn't work...